# Setting a pointer to NULL yields an "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" warning

Tags: c

I read the other questions about it, but still couldn't understand what is causing the warning I am getting.

```
char* func(const char* oldList) {
    static char* newList = NULL;

    if (oldList == NULL) {
        *newList = NULL;
    }
    ...
}
```

The warning I am getting is "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" (for the line `*newList = NULL`). Why?

Comment: Because `*newList` isn't a pointer; it is a `char`.  You need `newList = NULL;`.

Comment: That will yield a segmentation fault.

Comment: `newList` is `char*`, so `*newList` is a `char`. `NULL` is a pointer and assigning a pointer to a `char` raises a warning. And no, that won't raise a segmentation fault. Your current code will.

Comment: That line won't yield a segmentation fault written as `newList = NULL;` — abuse of `newList` afterwards might yield a segmentation fault.

Comment: if it raises an exception with that fix then there are problems somewhere else which was not shown by you. I don't see any unrelated comments here. Probably you just waste moderators' time

Answer (score 4):

`newList` is a pointer to a char.

`*newList` is the char the pointer points to.

So assigning `*newList = NULL` tries to assign a pointer (NULL) to a character - and therefore a cast.

In this specific code, even if you do some kind of casting, you still have segmentation fault, since `newList = NULL`.

You probably meant to write:

```
if (oldList == NULL) {
    newList = NULL;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, a "cast" is something like `(int) NULL`. What we have here is an invalid *conversion* from `void*` (I think that's what `NULL` is defined to be) to `char`, since there is no implicit conversion defined.

Comment: @Downvoter: NULL is a null pointer constant; it can be defined in various ways.  One of them is as `0`; sometimes, it will be given an appropriate suffix (such as `0ULL`) so that it is an integer of the correct type (the underlying type for `uintptr_t`); sometimes, it will be given as `((void *)0)`. When `NULL` is not cast to `void *`, people abuse it with `char c = NULL;` and then wonder why there are compiler warnings on platforms where `NULL` does contain the cast.  (Grrrr!!!! — aimed at the people who misuse `NULL` like that.)

Comment: Regarding casts and conversions: a cast is a way to explicitly force a conversion, by using the _`(type)`_ cast operator. Without it, conversions may still happen implicitly, on a case-by-case basis. By using a cast, you override the default conversion behavior for the given type. There is no cast in the posted code, just an invalid conversion. An invalid cast would be something like `orange_t orange; ... (apple_t) orange` where the types are structs.